# How can I deploy my web application In dedicated server using SQL Server and Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, static, dedicated-server, static-ip-address

I have a website developed in ASP.NET and SQL Server 2005. Now I have purchased a dedicated server to deploy the website.

I have trouble combining the Pleck Control Panel and my web server. How can I deploy my website on this web server usingPlesk Control Panel (cPanel).

Comment: will you use it with a domain or just ip address?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a support question typically meant for/addressed by, vendor (host) support and/or documentation.

Answer (score 0):

- Install web deploy to your server
- Create your website in iis
- Deploy your application using visual studio.
- Add a customer to your plesk panel (just add yourself)
- Add a website to customer you created (with domain you want to use with)
- Go to website options and disable hosting (This will allow iis to respond request coming to that domain)

Comment: I have published file of my website and .mdf file of database. I had attached database to sql server. Should I deploy the website from server machine to the server machine location? Plesk Control panel allow me to connect to the static ip(dedicated-webserver).But there is some problem connecting sql server of my dedicated web server.How can i solve it?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Can you give more details? What kind of problems you are facing?

Comment: This is still something that is much better to discuss with your hosting provider. There is very little we can do without much more information other than "there is a problem". There could be a million things wrong and many of them could be specific to your host setup, their environment, how you have setup your server, etc..

Comment: Ok..Sorry for this.I think I am not going to right direction.
Let me explain it in brief. Suppose I have a dedicated server, where I have created a database in SQL server of this web-server.Now I just want to access this data base from the Plesk C-panel, so I will be able to access this data base from website.So the question is "how can i use Plesk c-panel and dedicated-server(or static ip) simultaneously to access the data stored in the dedicated web server" ?